# Ubuntu 12.04 Lts Cpyrit-Cuda/pyrit/cpyrit-opencl install problems

Tags: 12.04

Hi im having a problem building and installing pyrit cpyrit-cuda and cpyrit opencl here is what im getting when i try to build and run the installer..

```
brandon@sanfran-Dell-System-Inspiron-N7110:~/cpyrit-opencl-0.4.0$ sudo python setup.py install
svn: '.' is not a working copy
running install
running build
running build_ext
Building modules...
building 'cpyrit._cpyrit_opencl' extension
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/local/cuda/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c _cpyrit_opencl.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_cpyrit_opencl.o -Wall -fno-strict-aliasing -DVERSION="0.4.0"
gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_cpyrit_opencl.o -lcrypto -lz -lOpenCL -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cpyrit/_cpyrit_opencl.so
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lOpenCL
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
brandon@sanfran-Dell-System-Inspiron-N7110:~/cpyrit-opencl-0.4.0$ f
```

Someone please help if possible all responses are greatly appreciated thanks!!

Comment: The OpenCL library is not found by the compiler. You can try to set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable with the folder in which your OpenCL library is installed.

Comment: and how do i do that cossacksman?? all helps appriciated bro im kind of a noob on ubuntu

Comment: Sorry for my brief answer, I was posting it from my phone... Now I'm at a Ubuntu PC and might be able to help better. I'll write detailed infor in the answer box below.

Comment: Argh! I mixed up LD_LIBRARY_PATH and LD_FLAGS. Sorry again! Answer is still in the making.

Answer (score 0):

The error message you got is telling you, that the OpenCL libary could not be found. Probably it isn't installed on your system, for Ubuntu *is supposed* to put a link to the OpenCL library in the default library folder /usr/lib.

In order to install OpenCL, install the proprietary graphics card drivers for your system. The tool "additional drivers" (program name: jockey) should help you find the appropriate package, but you can also install them manually. If you have an nVidia graphics card, this is probably the package nvidia-current or nvidia-current-updates for even newer versions. If you have an AMD graphics card, install fglrx or fglrx-updates. Do not use the *-experimental packages, for these (at least for AMD) do not include OpenCL functionality.

You might also need to install the opencl-headers package. On nvidia, there's a metapackage avialable, called nvidia-opencl-dev which should install everything needed to start working with OpenCL.

If your are certain that you installed OpenCL, and still don't get it running, find out where your libOpenCL.so file resides. Simply run

```
locate libOpenCL.so
```

This should give you a list of files of that name installed on your PC. In my case, there's a link "/usr/lib/libOpenCL.so", pointing towards the file itself, which is "/usr/lib/fglrx/libOpenCL.so". This means that in my case, the folder would be /usr/lib, or /usr/lib/fglrx. Once you know the folder name, you can run your install command again, but with LD_FLAGS set. I don't know how sudo reacts to setting variables, so I'd run an interactive root shell and set LD_FLAGS within:

```
sudo -i
LD_FLAGS="--library-path=<folder the lib is in>" python setup.py install
exit
```

If (for some strange reason, for instance if you didn't use Ubuntus graphics driver packages) your OpenCL lib is not installed in a default location (meaning: not in /usr/lib, /usr/local/lib or /lib), and there's also no symlink to it in one of these folders, I'd either put a symlink manually (the dirty, but easy hack), or write a file with the folder the lib is in and put it in /etc/ld.so.conf.d/ (have a look at the other files there to see what I mean and to check if it's not already there) and run "sudo ldconfig", in order for your programs to find it. The folders listed in files in /etc/ld.so.conf.d are a list of directories, that are searched for dynamic libraries by ldconfig, which in turn generates an index that is used by program to search for shared libraries.
Otherwise you might have to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH every time you run your compiled OpenCL application...

Comment: ok thanks for the detailed explanation so heres what i got i got the nvidia drivers installed along with bumblebee i have a optimus system with intel hd3000 and geforce 525m what im trying to do is get pyrit with cuda support working and i wiped clean the os previously installed giving me that error but im bout to try again so if you could point me to a good noob guide for installing pyrit with cuda support or if you kno how write me one up i would apprecate it greatly ive been rackin my brains on this for about a week lol

Comment: I'm afraid I have no experience with pyrit. I only set up OpenCL on my machine to use it with pyopencl.